# IE behaving weirdly

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, caching, http-headers

We are setting Window.Location through JavaScript depending on the value selected by the user in a dropdown. The url we are setting the location to does not have HTTP Caching set up explicitly.

However, we have observed that in certain cases, the expires header is set in the future by 1 second. Whenever this happens, changing window.location stops working for subsequent requests (even after waiting out for more than a second) as IE caches the response.

The Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2009 10:51:22 GMT
Expires: Wed, 04 Nov 2009 10:51:23 GMT
ETag: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 1.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 23405
```

Is there something wrong with what we are doing?

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you got the same issue with other browsers?

Comment: No happening with other browsers. Happening only on IE 7 and 8...but thats what our users use :(

Answer (score 0):

### Append a random parameter to the url.

So, instead of

```
window.location.href = 'somewhere.html';
```

you could use

```
window.location.href = 'somewhere.html?nocache=' + Math.random();
```

Since that "different" page is not in the cache yet, the browser will be forced to load it fresh.